# Java Multithreading can't stop thread

Tags: java, multithreading

This is a project for educational purposes I've got an array of threads, how can I check that all threads are currently waiting without using a while loop as the while loop causes an infinite loop.
I want to start the process using 100 threads and then increment the threads and re-start the operation until the difference in time between 100 and 101 threads for example is less than 250 milliseconds.

```
public class ThreadTime extends Thread {
    private static long[] results;
    private static int i = 100;

    public static int getI() {
        return i;
    }

    public void setI(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    public static long[] getResults() {
        return results;
    }
 
    public static void setResults(long[] results) {
        ThreadTime.results = results;
    }

    public void run(){
        System.out.println("Thread Started");
        Link link =new Link();
        link=LinkValidator.getMainQueue().pollFirst();
        LinkThread[] linkThreads = new LinkThread[1000];
        long start, end;
        results = new long[1000];
        do {
            System.out.println("Inside do");
            LinkValidator.getMainQueue().addLast(link);
            //notify();
            start=System.currentTimeMillis();
            for(int j=0;j<i;j++){
                System.out.println("inside j<i");
                linkThreads[j]=new LinkThread();
                linkThreads[j].start();
            }

            int k=0;
            while(k<i){
                System.out.println("inside k<i");
                 if(linkThreads[k].getState().compareTo(Thread.State.WAITING)==0){
                     System.out.println("Inside if");
                     k++;
                 }else {
                     System.out.println("Inside Else");
                     k=0;
                 }
             }
             i++;
             end=System.currentTimeMillis();
             results[i]=end-start;
         } while (results[i] - results[i - 1] > 250 || i < 102);
     }
}
```

Comment: By "waiting", do you mean `thread.getState() == Thread.State.WAITING`?

Comment: Better to post a version of your code stripped down to the bare minimum needed to display your issue.